# Positions and text length of bar plot labels

Tags: r, label, boxplot

I am having trouble with some labels.  I am doing bar plots in r and I am a little shocked there isn't an easy command to just place the values at the top.  Anyway, I want these labels to be more centered in the bars and to shorten the significant digits so they will fit within the bar.  I would also appreciate any suggestions on how to streamline this.

I have tried options(digits=5) and this did not work for the labels.  I have used text(plot.name, tmp, labels= c(tmp) but wanted to try and not use this to make it simpler.  I have to remake a lot a plots.

```
tmp = c(mean(1.0000001:100),mean(100.0000001:200), mean(200.0000001:300), mean(300.0000001:400))

barplot(tmp, names=c("site 1", "site 2", "site 3", "site 4") )

text(1:4, tmp, label=tmp, pos=2, srt=90)
```

Comment: why not just put it on the top? `text(bp, tmp, label=tmp, pos = 3, xpd = NA)` the text is easier to read if you don't have to turn your head. (bp is the return value of barplot)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I didnt want to put it on top for two reasons.  First, it gets cut off more often at the top of the plot, and second I don't like skewing the visualization by placing something onto of the bar however small it may be. Also, if it was horizontal it likely wouldn't fit.

Comment: 1) thats what `xpd = NA` is for; 2) `pos=3` puts the text *above* the bar and but some of the text doesn't fit in your vertical text example which is remedied by using round as in @koekenbakker's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The digits issue can be solved easily by using `round(tmp)`. As @rawr suggests, use the output of barplot to position the labels. Lastly, if you want to draw numbers above the bar, add `xpd=NA` to allow the number of the highest bar to be drawn outside the plot region.

```
bp = barplot(tmp, names=c("site 1", "site 2", "site 3", "site 4") )
# numbers above bars
text(x=bp, y=tmp, labels=round(tmp,0), pos=3, xpd=NA)
# numbers within bars
text(x=bp, y=tmp, labels=round(tmp,0), pos=1)
```